# Understanding/Restricting Azure Web App Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to understand how files and folders are restricted in Azure Web Apps.

Currently, it appears that none of the .dlls in my bin folder can be accessed, but a .dll in my App_Theme folder can.

Is there a logic behind what is publicly accessible and now?  Is there a way to lock down public access so that not everything can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a logic behind what is publicly accessible and now?

The **hiddenSegments** element contains a collection of `add` elements that identify certain URLs IIS  will make inaccessible to clients. We can get more detail about hiddenSegments from the [document](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments).

We also can remote to the Azure website to set it, about how to remote azure website using IIS-manager, please refer to another [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/).

> Is there a way to lock down public access so that not everything can be downloaded?

1.After we remote to azure website,in the Home pane double-click Request Filtering.

[image]

2.In the Request Filtering pane, click the Hidden Segments tab, and then click Add Hidden Segment. 
[image]

3.Try to access the file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If you know the name of your webapp you can skip to step 4 by navigating the to `https://{webappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net` else start at 1.

1. Login to your Azure Portal.
2. Open the blade for the WebApp in question.
3. Select "Advanced Tools" (formerly: "Kudo Tools")
4. Select the `Debug console` and then `CMD` or `PowerShell`
5. Execute the following command to make the file read only (i.e. as recommended for config files in many php projects): `attrib +r -a -s -h {file}`

**Command Explained:**

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490868(v=technet.10)

`+r` : Sets the read-only file attribute.

`-r` : Clears the read-only file attribute.

`+a` : Sets the archive file attribute.

`-a` : Clears the archive file attribute.

`+s` : Sets the system file attribute.

`-s` : Clears the system file attribute.

`+h` : Sets the hidden file attribute.

`-h` : Clears the hidden file attribute.

**Note:**

I have tried the following methods as per standard windows environments and they all failed:

- FTP (FileZilla & Windows Explorer)
- `CHMOD 664 {file}` (on CMD/PowerShell via Advanced/Kudu Tools from the WebApp blade)